# React js - data.map is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
export default function Case() {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const[data,setData]=useState([])
  const getcovid=async()=>{
    const api=await fetch('https://api.rootnet.in/covid19-in/stats/latest');
    const res=await api.json();
    console.log(res.data.summary)
    setData(res.data.summary)
  }
  useEffect(()=>{
    getcovid()
  },[])
    
  return (
      
    <div>
        <Typography variant="subtitle1" gutterBottom>
        Material-UI Grid:
      </Typography>
        {
            data&&data.map(item=>{
                return(
                <Grid container spacing={3}>
                <Grid item xs={3}>
                  <Paper className={classes.paper}>Confirmed Cases: <br/>{item}</Paper>
                </Grid>
                <Grid item xs={3}>
                  <Paper className={classes.paper}>xs=3</Paper>
                </Grid>
                <Grid item xs={3}>
                  <Paper className={classes.paper}>xs=3</Paper>
                </Grid>
                
                
              </Grid>
                )  
              
            })
        }
       
     
      </div>
  );
}
```

My api - {
"success": true,
"data": {
"summary": {
"total": 26289290,
"confirmedCasesIndian": 26289242,
"confirmedCasesForeign": 48,
"discharged": 23070365,
"deaths": 295525,
"confirmedButLocationUnidentified": 0
},

But it shows an error - TypeError: data.map is not a function
I have tried both with data&&data.map and only with data.map but still i get same error`enter code here`

Comment: Try to ``console.log(typeof data, data)`` to see what your data is.

Comment: Thanks, it's a string for some reason

Answer (score 1):

Your data is an `object` not an `array`. You can try to use this instead:

```
Object.keys(data).map(function(key, item) {
  console.log(data[key]);
   return(

    ...
   )
});
```

Comment: When i do this, it breaks the object into individual numbers, not the inputted data set. Is it possible to reformat the data that appears to be in an array format to be an actual array? I think it might be a string or something?

Comment: Please try ``Object.values(data).map(v=>{console.log(v)})``

Answer (score 1):

The API response you posted shows that `data.summary` is an object, not an array. Objects don't have a `map` method, but arrays do. Instead of using `map` you can just access the properties individually, such as `{data.total}` and `{data.deaths}`.